# Displaying an image in gallery intent

Tags: java, c#, android, image, xamarin

Is there any way to create an intent that will open that gallery and will show a specific image in there? I'm not asking about saving the image to the memory but I just want a proper and easy way to show the image (not in an ImageView) in such a way that zooming will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Intent` and `ACTION_VIEW` to achieve that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + "YOUR_FILE's PATH");
//Or you can use                 
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("YOUR_FILE's PATH"));
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're targeting or the device is API level 24+, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/8170714) to see how to get the proper Intent and avoid `FileUriExposedException`

Comment: Is it possible to do so without saving the image?

Comment: I think it has to be saved, at least to a temporary place. I don't think there's a way for gallery apps to resolve something from the memory directly.

Comment: By the way, is "file://" really needed?

Comment: If your file path already contains that then no, otherwise you have to include that so the system knows what kind of `Uri` it is. You can also use the `Uri.fromFile()` to get the `Uri` instance if you have a `File` instance

Comment: What's the file's path like? Are there any error logs?

Comment: I get `Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/pic1.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

Comment: Oh I see, I think you're probably targeting API 24+, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/8170714)

Comment: So I am supposed to check the user's API level?

Comment: Yes, I should rephrase it, if the device is above API 24, you have to do that

Comment: And isn't there any other way to zoom in an imageview?

Comment: There is probably a way to zoom in, but you asked for gallery intent in this question, that's why I answered that

Comment: Got you. By the way, I need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions?

Comment: I don't think so since you are not reading the file yourself, you are just providing it to a content provider. BUT if you want to save the file to a storage before this, you would need something like `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Wait.. I thought that I need the file's path, which means that I already saved it in the storage.

Comment: Yeah I know, if the file is already saved, you don't need any permission, but if you want to save it to storage, then you need the permission